Zod Validation Error: Invalid Input with Custom Type
I'm using Zod for schema validation in my job posting form, but I'm encountering an error that states:
{ "": { "message": "Invalid input", "type": "custom" } }

This error occurs when I attempt to validate my input data against the following schema:
import { z } from 'zod';

export const postJobSchema = z
  .object({
    title: z.string({ required_error: "Job Title should not be empty" }),
    client_name: z.string({
      required_error: "Client Name should not be empty",
    }),
    description: z.string({
      required_error: "Job Description should not be empty",
    }),
    email: z.string().email("Invalid E-mail").optional(),
    specialization: z.array(z.string()).optional(),
    job_type: z.string({ required_error: "Job Type should not be empty" }),
    role: z.string({ required_error: "Role should not be empty" }),
    skills_required: z
      .array(z.string())
      .min(1, "At least one skill is required"),
    min_offered_salary: z.string().optional(),
    max_offered_salary: z.string().optional(),
    career_level: z.string().optional(),
    min_year_of_experience: z.string().optional().default("0"),
    max_year_of_experience: z.string({
      required_error: "Year of Experience should not be empty",
    }),
    number_of_vacancy: z.string({
      required_error: "Number Of Vacancy should not be empty",
    }),
    min_notice_period_days: z.string().optional().default("0"),
    max_notice_period_days: z.string({
      required_error: "Notice Period should not be empty",
    }),
    industry: z.string().optional(),
    department: z.string().optional(),
    qualification: z.string().optional(),
    year_of_passout: z.string().optional(),
    key_responsibilities: z.string({
      required_error: "Key Responsibility should not be empty",
    }),
    visa_type: z.string({ required_error: "Visa Type should not be empty" }),
    country: z.string().optional(),
    location: z.string().optional(),
    deadline: z.string().optional(),
  })
  .refine((data) => 
      Number(data.min_year_of_experience) <= Number(data.max_year_of_experience),
      {
        path: ["max_year_of_experience"],
        message:
          "Max year of experience should be greater than or equal to min year of experience",
      }
  )
  .refine((data) => 
      Number(data.min_notice_period_days) <= Number(data.max_notice_period_days),
      {
        path: ["max_notice_period_days"],
        message:
          "Max Notice Period should be greater than or equal to min Notice Period",
      }
  )
  .refine((data) => {
      if (data.min_offered_salary && data.max_offered_salary) {
          return Number(data.min_offered_salary) <= Number(data.max_offered_salary);
      }
      return true; 
  }, {
      path: ["max_offered_salary"],
      message:
          "Max offered salary should be greater than or equal to min offered salary",
  });

I expect the validation to either succeed or provide detailed feedback on which fields are invalid.
Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this generic error message? What steps can I take to get more detailed validation errors from Zod?

add a sample data input which gives that error, will make it easier to figure out the root cause
